Increase glitch area in Adobe After Effects Template
I obtained a template from Envato Elements.
Here are some of the layers on the video.

I wanted to know how to go about making the "Your slogan here" area larger so that I fit more text.  There is a glitch effect for the text that appears in the "Text Glitch" layer.
When I click on the "Your slogan here" layer, only the text is selected and not the area that holds the text.
Please let me know if you require further screenshots.

You can achieve this with two ways.

Change the 200,5 Scale rate into something lower to fit your text in that area.
Change both of the layer's (Your slogan here & Text Glitch) resolution sizes from the "Composition Settings menu" into something bigger than default one (1500 x 300) to fit your text.


Be aware that when you make that text longer, Reflection is quite noticable. To edit or make it invisible you need to click the eye on the left side of the Reflection layer in the HI-tech Logo Reveal layer (just under Text Glitch layer).
